# Binary tree traversal with InOrder iterator, without stack

Tags: c++, tree, iterator, traversal, inorder

My task is to create a generic binary tree in C++, and I have to use iterators to traverse it, without using STL containers (such as stacks).

Here's all the source code so far: http://www35.zippyshare.com/v/98817061/file.html

Using recursive traversal, the tree is fully traversed (all the values appear on-screen), so my Insert function seems to work fine. This iterator however, doesn't seem to get to the right-side nodes (only 1 and 2 appears, the rest doesn't). Any ideas why?

Comment: It would be better if you posted the full program. `Any ideas why? ` Or better yet, why not use the debugger? If you use the debugger, you would more than likely answer the "why" question yourself (unless it is purely a C++ syntax/concept issue you don't understand, and not a logic flow or similar issue).

Comment: Here it is: http://www35.zippyshare.com/v/98817061/file.html

My code is a real mess right now, started this about 2 days ago, sorry about that ^^'
I'm using the VS 2013 debugger, which has no problems with it.